# Regex Replace in Mirasvit Sphinx Search

Tags: regex, magento, sphinx

I have a number of sku's listed on my site. The sku's found are 12 digits long. In my store they are listed on the product detail page as 8 chars.

Mirasvit Search has a function to replace this, however how it's supposed to work is a mystery...

I'm debugging the Sphinx Search Replace function on a an old magento store / client's website:
12 characters replace to 8 if regex matches following style:

```
/([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])/
```

Match Replace (4 characters)

```
([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])$
```

By

```
(empty)
```

I need to replace **166278010201** to **16241702** in order to show matching search results...

I've included the documentation:
https://mirasvit.com/doc/extension_searchsphinx/current/ssp/global/long_tail

Comment: Can you explain why `166278010201` would be replaced by `16241702`? It doesn't seem to be following any order. Perhaps you meant replaced by `16627801`?

Comment: What I mean is, do you want to replace a 12 digit number by the first 8 digits?

Comment: Yes, and I figured out how to do this in specific regex, however this does not fly with MirasVits SEO Sphinx regex settings...

Comment: Try: Match Expression - `/[0-9]{12}/`, Replace Expression - `/[0-9]{4}$/`, Replace Char - `empty`

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. You may post this as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

**Match Expression** - `/[0-9]{12}/`
**Replace Expression** - `/[0-9]{4}$/`
**Replace Char** - `empty`

This will find all 12-digit chunks of text and remove the last 4 digits from each match found.